# Getting the id for the select element in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic bootstrap table of 3 columns with multiple rows. The 3rd column is a select box with values in it. Now when the user clicks on a table row, I want the id of this select box value that is selected. I have this so far..

**JSP**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover spacer-top" id="tableSectionDetails"   name="tableSectionDetails" onclick="selectTableRowData();return false;">

<c:forEach var="subSection" items="${section.subSectionList}">
  <tr>
     <td>${section.sectionName}</td>
     <td>${subSection.subSectionName}</td>

     <td>
         <select name ="caseName" class="form-control">
             <c:forEach var="scase" items="${subSecction.SCaseList}">

                <option value="${scase.id}">${scase.caseName}</option>
             </c:forEach>
         </select>

     </td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach> 

</table>
```

**JS**

```
function selectTableRowData(){

     $('#tableSectionDetails tbody td').dblclick(function(){
         var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
         alert(rowIndex);  //shows the correct row index but it alerts the same index for all the rows table has instead of the selected row and just one time

         alert($("select.caseName[rowIndex]").text());  //empty...does not return the correct value and again alerts me multiple times (row times) instead of just one time selected row..


    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like your select dropdown does not have an ID to begin with

Comment: Do you mean you want the `scase.id` *value* that's been selected? http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: I think you mean value, not id.. to get the value of currently selected item `$('select option:selected').val();` or `$('select').val();`

Comment: Yes I dont have an id as of now, I removed it since thought id wouldnt solve much purpose. So, @Blazemonger yes i want scase.id

Comment: @JF I tried alert($('caseName').val()) but its alerting undefined. Also I get the alerts multiple times.

Comment: `alert($('[name="caseName"]').val());` try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#tableSectionDetails tbody td').dblclick(function(){
    var value = $(this).closest("tr").find("select").val();
});
```

Comment: Perfect!! that works! except for 1 glitch, which am trying to understand. If I were to alert this "value" i get alerted multiple times, is there a  way to avoid it so that when I am reading the value it is not read multiple times and hence avoid unnecessary looping.